# What does @a[-@a..-2] mean?

Tags: arrays, perl

Why does the third `print` fail?

```
my @a = (0,1,2,3); 
print @a[-@a..-2];  # works
print @a[0..2];     # works
print @a[0..-2];    # prints nothing
```

It's not clear to me the meaning of `-@a` used in this `@a[-@a..-2]` statement. Is this a special syntax? What does this special syntax provide (if at all) in addition to `$#a` for instance? Is it some sort of sugar (which is curious as it is shorter by only a single character) where the symbol for the array used in a subindex means "length of that array"?

Comment: -@a = -4, i.e. negative of the size of the array @a.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 3rd `print` prints nothing because, according to `perldoc perlop`:

> If the left value is greater than the right value then it returns the
>   empty list.

See also `perldoc B::Deparse`:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse code.pl
my(@a) = (0, 1, 2, 3);
print @a[-@a .. -2];
print @a[0..2];
print @a[()];
```

I believe `print @a[-@a..-2];` "works" because it is really like `@a[-4 .. -2]`.  According to `perldoc perldata`:

> A negative subscript retrieves its value from the end.

So, 3 is at index -1, 2 is at index -2, 1 is at index -3 and 0 is at index -4.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing special about `-@a`. In scalar context, `@a` returns the number of elements in the array, so `-@a` returns the negative of that number. e.g. If `@a` contains for elements, `@a` is `4` and `-@a` is `-4`.

So, for an array with four elements,

`@a[-@a..-2]` means `@a[-4..-2]`,

which means `@a[-4,-3,-2]`,

which means "the 4th element from the end, the 3rd element from the end, and the 2nd element from the end",

which means "elements 0, 1 and 2".

Comment: Oh okay. "scalar context" concept is still new to me

Comment: Each operator that can return something other than exactly one scalar must necessarily return something different in scalar context than in list context. It's up to each individual operator what to return.